Exclude zero values
I am very new to VBA and have picked up so code from a previous colleague and am trying to expand on it from their original intentions. It currently works and pulls all values from a 52 week year effectively unpivoting the data, however it is pulling through all data that has a zero in it, which I don't need.
Sub GetInWeekData()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tier 1")
    Set outputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableua")
    
    Dim check As Boolean, rn As Integer, Status As String, Region As String, outputrow As Long, kmsIssued As Double
    
    'retrieve week no from cell g4
    wkNo = Worksheets("Control").Range("E3")
    CP = Worksheets("Control").Range("E1")
    
    check = False: rn = 8: Region = "": outputrow = 2
    
    Do
        check = (Sheet.Cells(rn, 2).Value = "Control")
        rn = rn + 1
    Loop Until check = True
    
    For X = rn - 2 To 8 Step -1
        
        For Col = 9 To 60 Step 1
        
            Region = Sheet.Cells(X, 2).Value
            'Type = Status
            Status = Sheet.Cells(X, 4).Value
            
            If Sheet.Cells(X, 3).Value <> "" Then
                'add new row
                'region
                outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 1).Value = Region
                'DV
                outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 2).Value = Sheet.Cells(X, 3).Value
                
                'Type
                Select Case Status
                    Case "Current"
                        If Sheet.Cells(8, Col).Value <= wkNo Then
                            outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 3).Value = "A"
                        Else
                            outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 3).Value = "F"
                        End If
                    Case "Growth"
                        If Sheet.Cells(8, Col).Value <= wkNo Then
                            outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 3).Value = "A"
                        Else
                            outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 3).Value = "F"
                        End If
                    Case "Attraction"
                        If Sheet.Cells(8, Col).Value <= wkNo Then
                            outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 3).Value = "A"
                        Else
                            outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 3).Value = "F"
                        End If
                    Case "Target"
                        outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 3).Value = "T"
                End Select
                
                'CP
                outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 4).Value = CP
                'Wk
                outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 5).Value = Sheet.Cells(8, Col).Value
                'Metric
                outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 6).Value = "In Week Delivery"
                'Vol
                outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 7).Value = Sheet.Cells(X, Col).Value
                'Confidence
                outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 8).Value = Sheet.Cells(X, 5).Value
                'Tier
                outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 9).Value = Sheet.Cells(X, 7).Value
                outputrow = outputrow + 1
            
            End If
        
        Next
    
    Next X

End Sub

What I need it to do is, look whether the value with columns 9 to 60, and if it has a value above zero then perform the code as written. The Columns are defined but the number of rows can change hence the loop to find the lowest row number

Seems this will do what you need:
For X = rn - 2 To 8 Step -1
For Col = 9 To 60 Step 1

If Sheet.Cells(X, Col) > 0 Then    '*** Added
       
Region = Sheet.Cells(X, 2).Value
'Type = Status
Status = Sheet.Cells(X, 4).Value
   
    
    If Sheet.Cells(X, 3).Value <> "" Then
        'add new row
        'region
        outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 1).Value = Region
        'DV
        outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 2).Value = Sheet.Cells(X, 3).Value
        
        'Type
        Select Case Status
        Case "Current"
                    If Sheet.Cells(8, Col).Value <= wkNo Then
                        outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 3).Value = "A"
                    Else
                        outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 3).Value = "F"
                    End If
        Case "Growth"
                    If Sheet.Cells(8, Col).Value <= wkNo Then
                        outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 3).Value = "A"
                    Else
                        outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 3).Value = "F"
                    End If
        Case "Attraction"
                    If Sheet.Cells(8, Col).Value <= wkNo Then
                        outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 3).Value = "A"
                    Else
                        outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 3).Value = "F"
                    End If
        Case "Target"
        outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 3).Value = "T"
        End Select

        'CP
        outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 4).Value = CP
        'Wk
        outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 5).Value = Sheet.Cells(8, Col).Value
        'Metric
        outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 6).Value = "In Week Delivery"
        'Vol
        outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 7).Value = Sheet.Cells(X, Col).Value
        'Confidence
        outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 8).Value = Sheet.Cells(X, 5).Value
        'Tier
        outputSheet.Cells(outputrow, 9).Value = Sheet.Cells(X, 7).Value
  outputrow = outputrow + 1
  End If
  
End If   '***Added
  Next Col
  Next X



Option Explicit

Sub GetInWeekData()

    Dim wsIn As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet, wsControl As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long, c As Long, rowOut As Long
    Dim wkNo As String, CP As String
    Dim region As String, status As String, colC As String
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsIn = .Sheets("Tier 1")
        Set wsOut = .Sheets("Tableua")
        Set wsControl = .Sheets("Control")
    End With
    
    With wsControl
       CP = .Range("E1").Value2
       wkNo = .Range("E3").Value2
    End With
    
    ' find control at end of data
    With wsIn
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = wsIn.Range("B9:B" & lastrow).Find("Control", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    End With
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not find word 'Control'", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    Else
        lastrow = rng.Row - 1
    End If
    
    ' scan up
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    rowOut = 1
    For r = lastrow To 8 Step -1
        region = wsIn.Cells(r, 2)
        colC = wsIn.Cells(r, 3)
        status = wsIn.Cells(r, 4)
        If colC <> "" Then
            For c = 9 To 60
                ' skip zero values
                If wsIn.Cells(r, c) > 0 Then
                    rowOut = rowOut + 1
                    wsOut.Cells(rowOut, 1) = region
                    wsOut.Cells(rowOut, 2) = colC
                    Select Case status
                        Case "Current", "Growth", "Attraction"
                            If wsIn.Cells(8, c) <= wkNo Then
                                wsOut.Cells(rowOut, 3) = "A"
                            Else
                                wsOut.Cells(rowOut, 3) = "F"
                            End If
                        Case "Target"
                            wsOut.Cells(rowOut, 3) = "T"
                    End Select
                    
                    wsOut.Cells(rowOut, 4) = CP
                    wsOut.Cells(rowOut, 5) = wsIn.Cells(8, c) 'Wk
                    wsOut.Cells(rowOut, 6) = "In Week Delivery"
                    wsOut.Cells(rowOut, 7) = wsIn.Cells(r, c) 'Vol
                    wsOut.Cells(rowOut, 8) = wsIn.Cells(r, 5) 'Confidence
                    wsOut.Cells(rowOut, 9) = wsIn.Cells(r, 7) ' Tier
                End If
                
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
    ' result
    If rowOut > 1 Then
        MsgBox rowOut - 1 & " rows written to " & wsOut.Name & " in " _
           & Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs"), vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "No output created", vbExclamation
    End If
    
End Sub

